# Dask compute gives AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I would like to apply a function to each row of a dask dataframe.

Executing the operation with `ddf.compute()` gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

This is my code:

```
def polar(data):
    data=scale(sid.polarity_scores(data.tweet)['compound'])
    return data

t_data['sentiment'] = t_data.map_partitions(polar, meta=('sentiment', int))
```

And using `t_data.head()` also result in same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out the answer. You have to apply for partition.

```
t_data['sentiment']=t_data.map_partitions(lambda df : df.apply(polar,axis=1))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following:

```
t_data.apply(polar, axis=1)
```